# wondering how to COPY error text from Powershell

Tags: powershell, copy, copy-paste, paste

Since I have to manually rewrite error text when I encounter it, I'm wondering how to copy it from PowerShell. I know it seems silly, but I'm looking for a fix.

Comment: ```copy-item -Force -Confirm:$false``` should help or?

Comment: What do you mean by _Copy from PowerShell_?? Copy files? Copy ??? Please show us what you intend to do and what you have tried yourself already. (use the [edit] link to update your question)

Comment: @Theo I am trying to copy the output text

Comment: Ok, but isn't that normal Windows procedure? Select text -> Ctrl-C -> Ctrl-V

Comment: I couldn't copy text from PowerShell 
when clicking Ctrl+C it thinks am exiting

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
I select the text I want to copy, then, 
Before I release the left button, I press the right one.
```

Comment: Still not clear what you wanted to do here..

Comment: If QuickEdit mode is enabled in your (`conhost.exe`) console windows (it is by default, nowadays), then, yes, right-clicking after having made a selection is a quick way to copy that selection to the clipboard. But Ctrl-C should work too, because in selection mode it does _not_ terminate a running program, if any. /cc @Theo.